# Displaying 5 rows of data from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple table (mgap_orders) with customer orders in it. Multiple have the the same id (mgap_ska_id) and I simply want to pull 5 records from the table and display all five.

I can easily get one record with the following query and PDO, but how can I display 5 rows instead of only one row?

```
  $result_cat_item = "SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id' GROUP BY mgap_ska_id";

    while($row_cat_sub = $stmt_cat_item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $item=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_description'];
    $item_num=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_number'];
    $item_type=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_type'];
    $item_cat=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_catalog_number'];
    $item_ven=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_vendor'];
    $item_pur=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_percent_purchased'];
    $item_sales=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_sales'];
    }
```

Comment: Do you know which 5 rows?

Comment: Get rid of that daft GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `limit 5` then put the results in an array, like this:

```
$result_cat_item = "SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id' GROUP BY mgap_ska_id LIMIT 5";

$items = array();

while($row_cat_sub = $stmt_cat_item->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $items['item']       = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_description'];
    $items['item_num']   = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_number'];
    $items['item_type']  = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_type'];
    $items['item_cat']   = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_catalog_number'];
    $items['item_ven']   = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_vendor'];
    $items['item_pur']   = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_percent_purchased'];
    $items['item_sales'] = $row_cat_sub['mgap_item_sales'];
}
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    // echo $item['item'] or whatever
}
```

EDIT: Or you can skip putting them in the array and just use the `while()` to do what you need to do with the data.

Comment: You'll probably want to also sort the rows in a meaningful way (newest 5? by price? etc...)

Comment: @Samsquanch - Thanks for the help; worked like a charm!