# AJAX Call to SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using the following accordian to display two the result different queries: the accordian displays one row from a query and Im using an AJAX call to a second query to populate the the accordian content area. Here is my code and question:

Im getting the following error:

**Error: [object XMLHttpRequest]**

Here is my code:

**Accordian**

```
<div class="wrapper" >
   <div class="accButton" id="<?php echo $name;  ?>"> //this value comes from the query and is passed to the AJAX call
   <span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $record;  ?></span>
   <span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $name;  ?></span>
       //Accordian content area- This div accepts the return from the AJAC call
       <div class="accContent" id="output_element">   
       </div>
</div> //closing div for accordian button
```

**AJAX Call**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.accButton').click(function() {
var element = $(this);
var del_id2 = element.attr("id");
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "item_view.php",
   //data: info,
   data: {id2:del_id2},
   success: function(response){
      $("#output_element").html(response);
   },
              error: function(msg){
                alert("Error: "+msg);
            }

});
});
});
</script>
```

**item_view.php**

```
<?php

include('db.php');
$id = $_POST['id2'] ;
$name = $_POST['order_id'] ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id' GROUP BY mgap_item_description LIMIT 5";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql); 
$items = array();
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => '$id'));

    while($row_cat_sub = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $items['item']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_description'];
    $items['item_num']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_number'];
    $items['item_type']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_type'];
    $items['item_cat']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_catalog_number'];
    $items['item_ven']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_vendor'];
    $items['item_pur']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_percent_purchased'];
    $items['item_sales']=$row_cat_sub['mgap_item_sales'];
    }

    foreach($items as $item) {
    ?>          
      <span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $item;  ?></span>
      <span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $item_num;  ?></span>
      <span class="growthcust">$<?php echo $item_type;  ?></span>
      <span class="namecustcoltype"><?php echo $item_cat;  ?></span>
      <span class="namecusttype"><?php echo $item_ven;  ?></span>
      <span class="growthcust">$<?php echo $item_pur;  ?></span>
      <span class="growthcust">$<?php echo $item_sales;  ?></span>                
    <?php
}
            ?>
```

Comment: press f12, the browser console will give you more clues

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying 5 rows of data from query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636096/displaying-5-rows-of-data-from-query)

Comment: its not a duplicate post...Im using the same solution (it was my post) now in an ajax call...and the console doesnt show me any output in chrome

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I didnt even know about the console...what a huge help. Everything is working well except its only working on the first row...any ideas? I have updated my code above. BTW the rows are being returned in the console, just not working in the page (except on the first row) so the sql is working.

Comment: Shouldn't the `SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '$id' GROUP BY mgap_item_description LIMIT 5` be `SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = :id GROUP BY mgap_item_description LIMIT 5`?  The change being `'$id'` to `:id`?

Comment: Matthew, when I change the $ to : I lose the functionality altogether. Its almost like I need a catalyst somewhere, but my accordian divs (button and output) are already in the 'while' statement and all rows are displaying as needed. For some reason the accordian is only opening on the first row. The other rows move when clicked, they just dont open.

Comment: @user3105700 The OP is using jQuery's `$.ajax(...);` method...

Comment: @TechnoCripple I could be wrong but I believe what _MatthewJohnson_ was setting you up for is binding the parameters. [See this reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). I've never used PDO myself. I prefer `MySQLi`. However, the concept is the same. (1) Prepare a statement with placeholders. (2) Bind parameters to the placeholders. (3) Execute the statement. (4) Retrieve the results.

Comment: I built my other PDO statements just like that reference, but when I remove the variable (S) delineator from the SQL everything stops working. When it is left as is, all works fine, but just on the first row.

Comment: BTW the regular jQuery accordion widget also does the same thing! What am I missing?